# Add a new key (array) in an existing json object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http, push

I've got an array with objects. I need for each object to add a key, which will be an array of other objects.

So my code looks like this:

```
$scope.array = [];

$http.get(url).success(function(data) {

   $scope.array = data;

   // Now my array has some objects
   var i = 0;
   function() getSomeData(i) { 
      if(i<array[i].length()) {
         $http.get(url + array[i].someKey).success(function(data){
            $scope.array[i].push(data);
            i++;
            getSomeData(i);
         })
      } 
   }

})

getSomeData(0);
```

But I am getting `Error:array.push is not a function`

Why's that happening ?

Comment: before you do `$scope.array = data;` can you tell us what is the output of `alert(typeof data);`

Comment: the type of data is object

Comment: There's no `array` variable in this script.

Comment: can you tell us what is the output of `alert(Array.isArray(data));`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to push to an object instead of the array. Either do:

`$scope.array.push(data)` to add a new object.

or do
`$scope.array[i] = data` to update the object at the specific index in the array.

Comment: I actually need to update the object at the specific index in the array by adding the data as key of the object.

Comment: @Korte, well you can access the objects by doing $scope.array[i].keyname So if you have a key named "foo" and you want to set the value to "bar", do $scope.array[i].foo = "bar".

Answer (score 0):

Objects in JSON are added using below two techniques. You can try one of them.

```
object["property"] = value;
```

or

```
object.property = value;
```